# How to make \hfill \break a little bit shorter in a single case?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

I start a new paragraph with a `\hfill \break` in my document. It works well, and looks well.

However, in a single instance, I think it would look much better, if the spacing between the paragraph would be a little bit shorter.

Can I somehow do it? Intuitively, I am thinking on something like `\lineheight{8pt}{\hfill \break}` or some similar.

Comment: (1) Why don't you start new paragraphs as they are supposed to, i.e. with blank lines? (2) You say it would look better "*if it would be a little shorter*". What is "*it*"? And what do you mean by "shorter"?

Comment: @campa (1) I tried. So it will be too short. The `\hfill \break` is my experimental googling-trial-error solution to create some extra spacing between the paragraphs. (2) On "shorter" I try to understand "lesser height". For example, if the default spacing between the paragraphs would be 12pt, then 8pt would be shorter. It would be *niedriger* on German. Probably it is not the correct word on neither language. :-( Feel free to edit the post, I tried to do what I could.

Comment: Without an MWE illustrating what you want to do, or at least a sketch, I can only guess what you really want to achieve. And under normal circumstances I would *never* recommend this, but have you tried adding `\vspace{}` with a negative value, such as `\vspace{-5pt}`? (And, I really advise against tempering with paragraphs manually like this, I am sure, there must be a "proper" solution.

Comment: @MarkusG. Yeah! Thanks, it works! At first, latex looked for me totally different than html/css, but now I see more and more deep structural similarities. You can make an answer from it for an up + accept.

Comment: There you go. But in the language of html/css, consider this a manipulation of your html code, when really you typically want to modify your css (aka preamble) to make the document look like you want it to look.

Comment: @MarkusG. That is right. I think here is the time where I need to learn the "css of the latex".

Comment: `\hfill\break` does not start a paragraph in tex so your question is rather strange, it adds a linebreak mid-paragraph` (it should never be used in latex)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Wow, thanks! And how can I do what a `<br/>` does in html? I found this by googling and trial/error, seems working.

Comment: `\\ ` is the latex equivalent of br  although it should very rarely be used in latex, normally you want automatic breaking or end of paragraph (a blank line in the source)  that is: br doesn't start a paragraph in html either,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Okay. So I have a new paragraph, for example by a blank line. How can change the spacing in a single case?

Comment: after the blank line add `\vspace{3in}` as suggested in the posted answer (but leave a blank line before the vspace (vspace mid-paragraph has a defined behaviour but possibly not what you expect) try  `.... one \vspace{1cm} two ...  `` with and without a blank line before the vspace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am making this an answer by request. As I stated in my comment above, trying to manipulate the lineheight and distance of paragraphs manually is not really something I recommend.

But in this particular use-case vertical lengths can be influenced by adding either `\vspace{}` or `\vspace*{}` using a negative length. E.g. `\vspace{-5pt}`.

Comment: In general, I agree your view (auto-rendered things are better than manually). But this is an exception (I have strong constraints on the pixel-level positionings, while I need not to handle an unspecified content flow).

Comment: I am glad I could help with your use-case. I just wanted to make sure, anyone else who finds this answer does not treat it as a go-to solution. Because in general, it really isn't. But then again, LaTeX gives you this option, so it is up to everyone to decide for themselves, how they want to implement it.